# $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$. If $\mathbb R^3$ equipped with sup norm is f be bounded? If so find $\Vert f\Vert.$

Tags: functional-analysis

It's very easy to see $f$ is bounded with respect to 2-norm which I've already done.
$$|f(x,y,z)|\leq|a||x|+|b||y|+|c||z|$$
             $$\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\Vert(x, y, z)\Vert.$$
Then $\Vert f(x,y,z)\Vert\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$
And at the point $\frac{(a, b, c)}{\Vert(a, b, c)\Vert}$
Gives $\Vert f\Vert$.
I can also tell that $\mathbb R^3$ is of finite dimensional. So sup norm and this 2 norm are equivalent. But then I can't proceed... 
What will happen if two norms are equivalent? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the definition of the norm of an operator from $A$ to $B$ is:

> $\|f\|_{op} = \sup\limits_{\|t\|_A=1}\{\|f(t)\|_B\}$

In this case, $t$ is a $3$-tuple, $(x,y,z)$, and we take the sup norm of the 3-tuple.  When $\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty=1$ is whenever $|x|,|y|$ or $|z|=1$ and the others are $\leq 1$.  It is plain to see that this is maximized when $x=sgn(a), y=sgn(b), z=sgn(c)$ so you have $f(x,y,z)=|a|+|b|+|c|$

As such, the operator norm in this case is $|a|+|b|+|c|$.  You have that for any $(x,y,z)$, you have $|f(x,y,z)|\leq (|a|+|b|+|c|)\cdot \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}$.  This can be seen a different way as well:

$\begin{align}|f(x,y,z)| = |ax+by+cz|\\
\leq |a||x|+|b||y|+|c||z|\\
\leq |a|\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}+|b|\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}+|c|\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\} \\
= (|a|+|b|+|c|)\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}\\
=(|a|+|b|+|c|)\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty\end{align}$

Noting that the $\leq$'s are in fact equalities when $ax, by$ and $cz$ are all positive and that $|x|=|y|=|z|$ shows that the bound is tight.

Comment: But (1,1,1) gives a+b+c...how ||f||=|a|+|b|+|c|?

Comment: Keep in mind that any of a, b, c could be negative as well.  The triangle inequality gives that $ a+b+c\leq |a+b+c| \leq |a|+|b|+|c|=ax+by+cz $ when $ x= sgn (a) $ etc.  If you aren't familiar with notation, $ sgn (a)=\frac{a}{|a|} $ unless a is zero.  I . e,  sgn of a positive number is 1, of a negative number is -1, and of zero is zero.